# codigo de comparacion de bits c++

Tags: c++

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
    cout << "Introducir numeros a y b" << endl;

    unsigned int a;
    cin >> a;
    unsigned int b;
    cin >> b;
    unsigned int a16= a<<16;
    unsigned int b16= b>>16;
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<b<<endl;
    if ((a16+b16)>735){
      unsigned int a12=a>>12;
      unsigned int b8= b>>8;
      if(a12==b8){


        
              

        else {
          cout<<"Esos no son los androides que buscas"            <<endl;
          exit();
        }
      }



    else{
      cout<<"Eso no es correcto"<<endl;
      exit();
    } 
  }
  
}
```

En un trabajo me piden un código que compara el bit numero 12 de una variable *unsigned* de 32 bits con el bit numero 8 de otra variable como la anterior y luego ya que salga por pantalla si son iguales o no.

Este es el código que he intentado hasta ahora. El primer apartado selecciona los 16 primeros bits de la primera variable y los 16 ultimos bits de la segunda variable, y mediante una suma luego comprueba si el valor resultante es mayor a 735, eso creo que ya esta.

El problema viene en lo que comento al principio, que no se como seleccionar el bit de una posicion de un numero.

Comment: Te aporto un código que te vendrá bien... `if (codigo_intentado_adjuntado == 1) { intentamos_ayudarte(); } else { pedir_codigo_intentado++; }`. En este foro se intenta ayudar con dudas pero **NO SE HACEN DEBERES**. Adjunta el código que has intentado, las dudas que tienes, qué errores te salen... Y así podremos ayudarte

Comment: gracias fenomeno llevo toda la tarde intentando hacerlo y buscando informacion sobre ello pero no encuentro nada por eso es que recurro a gente que sabe mas que yo para que me den una ayuda, no pido que se me escriba un codigo entero solo pido que se me indique por donde tengo que ir para resolver por mi mismoelproblema

Comment: pero para ser la primera respuesta que me encuentro al entrar por primera vez a un foro de programacion nose si he ido a parar al lugar adecuado, seguire informandome sobre como resolver el problema en otro sitio....

Comment: Te vuelvo a repetir, estamos encantados de ayudarte, pero inserta el código que has intentado, qué errores te dan, qué has probado, etc. No te vamos a hacer la tarea del colegio. De todos modos, si este foro no te "sirve" te recomiendo echar un vistazo a operadores binarios de desplazamiento `>>` y   `<<`

Comment: ahi tienes aunque ya probe varias veces con el desplazamiento en mas pruebas que hice pero no me da el resultado que quiero, no se si el ejercicio tira mas por usar las mascaras de bits con los xor and...

Comment: esos exit del final son para mas adelante dejarlo como una funcion que juntada con otras mas ya puedan hacer su funcion

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código en formato de código y no en imagen? De este modo podremos coger tu código y compilarlo en nuestros PCs. Me niego a transcribir a mano tu código de la foto en mi PC.

Comment: Ahí esta puesto todo

Comment: Te he puesto una solución con un código sencillo que no tiene que ver con el tuyo, porque tu código no tiene ni pies ni cabeza. No sé qué querías conseguir con `if(a12==b8){ else {`, pero desde luego no tiene sentido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución que puedes emplear para ver si los bits 12 y 8 de los números que quieres puede ser la siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MASK_NUM1 0x0800 // De los 32 bits que hay, sólo el 12 está a 1
#define MASK_NUM2 0x0080 // De los 32 bits que hay, sólo el 8 está a 1

int main() {
    unsigned int numero1, numero2;
    bool bit12_numero1, bit8_numero2;

    cout << "Numero 1: ";
    cin >> numero1;
    cout << "Numero 2: ";
    cin >> numero2;

    // Hacemos una máscara para solo valorar los bits de interés y después desplazamos el bit de interés a la primera posición
    bit12_numero1 = (numero1 & MASK_NUM1) >> 11;
    bit8_numero2 = (numero2 & MASK_NUM2) >> 7;

    if ( bit12_numero1 == bit8_numero2 )
        cout << "El bit 12 del numero 1 y el bit 8 del numero 2 son iguales";
    else
        cout << "El bit 12 del numero 1 y el bit 8 del numero 2 son distintos";

    return 0;
}
```

Te explico lo que hacemos..

1. Definimos dos máscaras, una para el primer número que afecte al bit 12, y otra para el segundo número que afecte al bit 8.
2. Insertamos los números de 32bits sin signo y los almacenamos en `numero1` y `numero2`.
3. Como queremos comparar el bit 12 de `numero1` y el bit 8 de `numero2`, por lo que hacemos una `AND` con las respectivas máscaras mediante la operación `numer1 & MASK_NUM1`, de este modo tendremos todos los bits a 0 y el bit 12 con el valor que tenga. Luego mediante el operador binario `>>` desplazamos ese bit 12 (el que nos interesa) hasta la posición del primer bit. Este paso lo hacemos también para la variable `numero2`. Almacenamos ese resultado en dos variables booleanas: `bit12_numero1` y `bit8_numero2`, que son los bits que nos interesan.
4. Ahora solo nos queda comparar el valor de esas variables de resultado que hemos obtenido y realizar un simple `if-else` para comprobar si son iguales.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, y para la próxima vez, si te dicen que es conveniente que modifiques la pregunta, hazlo.

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias tu respuesta me ha sido de increible ayuda me has solucionado un problema que me lleva dando un dolor de cabeza durante varios dias, debo de darte una disculpa por las formas. A partir de ahora hare lo que me has dicho maestro!

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta no olvides marcarla como correcta para que en el futuro sirva a la gente

Comment: @CarlosZapicoBello Tal como te ha indicado Londo, si la respuesta soluciona tu pregunta, deberias marcarla como aceptada. En este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás como hacerlo. También, al ser un nuevo colaborador del sitio, deberias "estudiar" un poco como funcionamos, y realizar el [tour] que son dos minutos de tu vida y evitarán futuros malentendidos con los "veteranos" del lugar. Personalmente, cuando voy a un sitio nuevo, me fijo como funciona y no doy por supuesto nada para no meter la pata :-)  Bienvenido a [es.so]!